# Special case of counting empty cells "before" an occupied cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, counting

Pandas question here.

I have a specific dataset in which we are sampling subjective ratings several times over a second. The information is sorted as below. What I need is a way to "count" the number of blank cells before every "second" (i.e. "1" in the second's column that occur at regular intervals), so I can feed that value into a greatest common factor equation and create somewhat of a linear extrapolation based on milliseconds. In the example below that number would be "2" and I would feed that into the GCF formula. The end goal is to make a more accurate/usable timestamp. Sampling rates may vary by dataset.

| index | rating | seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 |  |
| 2 | 28 |  |
| 3 | 30 | 1 |
| 4 | 33 |  |
| 5 | 40 |  |
| 6 | 45 | 1 |
| 7 | 50 |  |
| 8 | 48 |  |
| 9 | 49 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide the exact expected output for clarity. Do you just need a single number of one for each `1`? If yes in which format?

Comment: Ideally, this would same to some variable. In this case something like empty_cells = 2. Then I would know to add 1 to count the full cells to get 3. I would then do 1000/3=333.3 to resample to a milliseconds and then have a new column with the index number times 333.3 (rounded to an integer) to get my timestamp). (So most of I think I can do, I am just stuck on that first part).

Comment: Please edit the question, you can paste formatted data in the comments. Also what is in your "empty" cells? NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of NaNs before the first `1`:

```
df['seconds'].isna().cummin().sum()
```

If you have another value (e.g. empty string)

```
df['seconds'].eq('').cummin().sum()
```

Output: `2`

Or, if you have a range Index:

```
df['seconds'].first_valid_index()
```